# JSON data extraction and write to DIV | Chat&Call APP | ZegoCloud

Tags: javascript, json, chat, zegocloud

newbie here, I need help with a Chat integration:

Here is a **Function** which I use to **send message**:

```
 ZegoExpressManager.shared.sendBroadcastMessage(
          config.roomID,
          "hello world!"
        );
```

With this one I **receive** it to my **ConsoleLog**:

```
 ZegoExpressManager.shared.onIMRecvBroadcastMessage(
        async (roomID, messageInfo) => {
        console.log("onIMRecvBroadcastMessage", roomID, messageInfo);}
```

**ConsoleOutput**:

```
{"time":"2022/07/09 12:34:40.611","level":1,"action":"zm.lrh.hsp","content":"push {\"header\":{\"sub_cmd\":\"/lr/push/im_chat\",\"msg_id\":\"1381362731MBy20xcWHa212374460\",\"send_time\":\"1657362880492\",\"room_id\":\"MBy20xcWHa\",\"sender_user_nid\":\"12443410347985956212\"},\"body\":{\"msg_data\":[{\"id_name\":\"935384446\",\"nick_name\":\"web-935384446\",\"msg_id\":\"31\",\"msg_category\":1,\"msg_type\":1,\"msg_priority\":1,\"msg_content\":\"\\hello world!\",\"send_time\":\"1657362880490\"}],\"room_id\":\"MBy20xcWHa\",\"server_msg_id\":\"31\",\"ret_msg_id\":\"31\"}}","appid":1381362731,"roomid":"MBy20xcWHa","userid":"719676606","userName":"","sessionid":""}
```

Now i need to extract "**msg_content**" and **write it into a div**

Thank You !

*Here is Console **Output as Text***

> {"time":"2022/07/09
> 12:34:40.611","level":1,"action":"zm.lrh.hsp","content":"push
> {"header":{"sub_cmd":"/lr/push/im_chat","msg_id":"1381362731MBy20xcWHa212374460","send_time":"1657362880492","room_id":"MBy20xcWHa","sender_user_nid":"12443410347985956212"},"body":{"msg_data":[{"id_name":"935384446","nick_name":"web-935384446","msg_id":"31","msg_category":1,"msg_type":1,"msg_priority":1,**"msg_content":"\hello+world"**,"send_time":"1657362880490"}],"room_id":"MBy20xcWHa","server_msg_id":"31","ret_msg_id":"31"}}","appid":1381362731,"roomid":"MBy20xcWHa","userid":"719676606","userName":"","sessionid":""}

**THIS is What im Trying**

**JSON.parse()**

```
  const message = JSON.parse(messageInfo);
      document.write(message.msg_content);
```

**Output**

[{"fromUser":{"userID":"72219676606","userName":"web-72219676606"},"message":"\nhallooo","sendTime":1657368483227,"messageID":55}]

**@uminder 's Solution ends with following stacktrace**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'substring')
> at call.php?userID=9985SAS720&roomID=MZ9gK86EYN:266:40
> at ZegoExpressManager.js:2:1299729
> at Array.forEach ()
> at e.actionListener (ZegoExpressManager.js:2:1299702)
> at e.handlePushRoomMsg (ZegoExpressManager.js:2:824050)
> at e.h [as handlePushRoomMsg] (ZegoExpressManager.js:2:814651)
> at e.handleSwitchPush (ZegoExpressManager.js:2:1334477)
> at e.handlePush (ZegoExpressManager.js:2:1333077)
> at ZegoExpressManager.js:2:1330411
> at ZegoExpressManager.js:2:1139037 (anonymous) @ call.php?userID=9985SAS720&roomID=MZ9gK86EYN:266 (anonymous) @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2 e.actionListener @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2
> e.handlePushRoomMsg @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2 h @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2 e.handleSwitchPush @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2
> e.handlePush @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2 (anonymous) @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2 (anonymous) @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2
> setTimeout (async) (anonymous) @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2 e.emit @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2 e.onPushEvent @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2
> e.onPushEvent @ ZegoExpressManager.js:2 onPushEvent @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2 socketService.onMessage @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2 socket.socket.onmessage @
> ZegoExpressManager.js:2

Answer (score 1):

You'll first have to extract, normalize and `parse` the relevant nested `JSON`.

```
const content = messageInfo.content;
const contentJSON = JSON.parse(content.substring(content.indexOf('{')).replace(/\\/g, ''));
```

Then, you can access the `msg_content`. Since `msg_data` is an `array`, you may find several of them.

```
const msgContent = contentJSON.body.msg_data.map(v => v.msg_content).join('\n');
```

Finally you assign the result to the `innerText` of the `div`.

```
document.querySelector('#msgContent').innerText = msgContent;
```

Please take a look at below code and see how it works.

```js
const messageInfo = {
  "time": "2022/07/09 12:34:40.611",
  "level": 1,
  "action": "zm.lrh.hsp",
  "content": "push {\"header\":{\"sub_cmd\":\"/lr/push/im_chat\",\"msg_id\":\"1381362731MBy20xcWHa212374460\",\"send_time\":\"1657362880492\",\"room_id\":\"MBy20xcWHa\",\"sender_user_nid\":\"12443410347985956212\"},\"body\":{\"msg_data\":[{\"id_name\":\"935384446\",\"nick_name\":\"web-935384446\",\"msg_id\":\"31\",\"msg_category\":1,\"msg_type\":1,\"msg_priority\":1,\"msg_content\":\"\\This+is+my+message\",\"send_time\":\"1657362880490\"}],\"room_id\":\"MBy20xcWHa\",\"server_msg_id\":\"31\",\"ret_msg_id\":\"31\"}}",
  "appid": 1381362731,
  "roomid": "MBy20xcWHa",
  "userid": "719676606",
  "userName": "",
  "sessionid": ""
};

const content = messageInfo.content;
const contentJSON = JSON.parse(content.substring(content.indexOf('{')).replace(/\\/g, ''));
const msgContent = contentJSON.body.msg_data.map(v => v.msg_content).join('\n');
document.querySelector('#msgContent').innerText = msgContent;
```

```html
<div id="msgContent"><div>
```

Comment: thank you for your Time: i got an **error   [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')]  ... >>>Stacktrace is up on Edit**